# SOAP Client error list array read

Tags: php, arrays, soap, soap-client

When I try to read from a function returning a list array or map array I have an error, can anyone help me? This is my code:

```
<?php
$serverAddress = "YOUR_SERVER_IP";
$serviceUrl = "http://127.0.0.1/soap-live/";
$wsdlUrl = $serviceUrl . 'wsdl/';
$clientParams = array(
  'login' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'paris',
  'location' => $serviceUrl,
  'trace' => true,
  'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
);
$client = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $clientParams);
echo "===== Get_api_version( ) =====<br/>\n";
$response = $client->Get_input_info(1);
echo $response->return . "<br/>\n";
?>
```

Best Regards.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in E:\AppServ\www\alaa.php on line 15

Comment: what do you get when var dumping the $response->return?

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in E:\AppServ\www\alaa.php